# Proving the convergence of a product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, products

I have become interested in taking the $n^{th}$ term of a series and evaluating a product whose $n^{th}$ term is $(1+a_n)$. After looking around I came across the following inequality:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \leq \prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+a_n)\leq \exp(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n)$

I was wondering if anyone had a proof, or could offer any suggestions of a proof, for this inequality. By assuming $a_k>0$, I have managed to prove that the product is less then the exponential using $1+a_k \leq e^{a_k}$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the first inequality, just try writing out a partial product and notice that you get the sum as part of the product. Adding some nonnegative things means the product is at least as large as the sum.

Comment: For the second equality, realise that $exp(a) \geq 1+a$ for all $a\geq 0$.